# This method won't work... Is it a syntax error?

Tags: java, syntax

So, I've been having issues with this. I'm trying to make this method return the first character of the string given to it, but I keep getting java.util.NoSuchElementException... I think I may be using some syntax wrong but really I have no idea. Any help?

```
public static char nthChar (){
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
 String input = sc.nextLine();
 char [] userCharArray = new char[input.length()];
 userCharArray = input.toCharArray();
 sc.close();
 return userCharArray[0];
}
```

Note that I imported the static members of java.lang.System
I changed it to this...

```
public static char nthChar (){
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 String input = sc.nextLine();
 char [] userCharArray = input.toCharArray();
 sc.close();
 return userCharArray[0];
}
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Where's `in` from in this static method?

Comment: userCharArray must be empty

Comment: You assign a `new char[]` to `userCharArray` and immediately after you reaffect it to the result of `input.toCharArray()` -- why?

Comment: @fge It wasn't like that before, I was just trying it. It doesn't work the other way either.

Comment: `.toCharArray()` will allocate the array for you, so no need to do that.

Comment: Where (what line) is the error being thrown?

Comment: SHOW US THE EXCEPTION STACK TRACE!!!

Comment: (Any time you report an exception you should show enough of the stack trace to identify the failing line.)

Comment: -1 because you never showed us the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the suspect to me:

```
sc.close();
```

When you close that Scanner, you are also closing System.in. Subsequent reads from a new Scanner reading from System.in will throw NoSuchElementException because the underlying stream is closed.

So you need to remove that and also look through your code and make sure you are not closing System.in elsewhere. Although usually you should close your streams when you are done with them, System.in is a special case and you don't need to (and shouldn't) close a stream that's reading from it.

For example, this will throw a NoSuchElementException:

```
Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
in1.close();
Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in2.nextLine(); // throws the exception
```

Comment: Upvoted because it IS correct. Tested using my little test program that was a part of my answer but calling `nchar()` multiple times.

Comment: The thing is, the line is read before stdin is closed... It is really the `.nextLine()` which throws the exception.

Comment: @fge I assume the OP is reading from System.in elsewhere before the nthChar method is called and also closing a Scanner there. (If calling nthChar doesn't work once.)